# Difference between $\mathbb{E}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, euclidean-geometry

Basically what is the difference between $\mathbb{E}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n $?
Simple question I know but I cannot think of what to type into google to get a proper answer.

Comment: There may be other usages, but in my experience they’re synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb {E}^n $ is a linear vector space of dimension $n $ for which there is a function, called *inner product* that is defined for each pair of vectors of $\mathbb {E}^n$ and that returns a scalar. When that inner product is defined we call the space an *Euclidean Space*. We know nothing about *what* the vectors actually *are*. We just know that the inner product exists and satisfies some axioms (in order to be an inner product the function must obey some rules). $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a specific example of an $n $-dimensional Euclidean Space where the vectors are what we know as those "arrows". And that is because we know how to define an *inner product* for $\mathbb {R}^n$.